# How to send email acording "Error%" of aggregate reportor in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to use "SMTP Sampler" sends email acording to "Error%" of aggregate reportor in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access listener values from JMeter script.

What you can do:

1. Use [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) (or [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener)) to check whether request is successful - the most recent request status lives in [${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) variable
2. If the request is not successful - increment a [counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter)
3. If the `counter` value exceeds threshold - send an email. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) for details on how to send email message from JMeter test script.